# Launching url through shell script on embedded linux

Tags: linux

I have linux based device and I need to launch a url from it. So that I am writing a shell script for it which should launch a url on my m/c. Is there any way by which we can launch url through shell script in embedded linux environment?

Comment: URL only locates resource. What application are you using to access the URL?

Comment: I have device which has embeded linux installed and I have web UI in it. I want to download file thru it and for that I need server side scripting but I do not have any other option than using shell script. I want to open a url from where I download a file so I want to open that url thru shell script. Please let me know whether it is possible to open any http request thru shell script.

Comment: Use either of wget or curl?

Comment: I am using wget but the problem is I dont know how to stop or pause download. Do u have any idea?